# Refresh node.js data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am new to node.js programming. I have a script running on my raspberry pi, providing a web interface to change settings and save them into a file.

Now, I also want to disply information on the page with the form that automatically refreshes, when another file, let's call it position.txt is changed.

How can I do this?
My code up to now:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');
var postHTML =
  '<html><head><title>Post Example</title></head>' +
  '<body>' +
  '<form method="post">' +
  'Richtung:<br><select name="input1" size="1">' +
  '<option value="1">Rueckwaerts</option>' +
  '<option value="2">Vorwaerts</option>' +
  '<option value="0">Stop</option>' +
  '<option value="3">ENDE</option>' +
  '</select><br><br>' +
  'Geschwindigkeit:<br><select name="input2" size="1">' +
  '<option value="010">1</option>' +
  '<option value="020">2</option>' +
  '<option value="030">3</option>' +
  '<option value="040">4</option>' +
  '<option value="050">5</option>' +
  '<option value="060">6</option>' +
  '<option value="070">7</option>' +
  '<option value="080">8</option>' +
  '<option value="090">9</option>' +
  '<option value="100">10</option>' +
  '</select><br><br>' +
  '<input type="submit">' +
  '</form>' +
  '</body></html>';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var body = "";
  var in1 = "";
  var in2 = "";
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });

  req.on('end', function () {
    var gesamt = qs.parse(body);
    in1 = gesamt['input1'];
    in2 = gesamt['input2'];
    var erg = in1+in2;
    fs.writeFile('befehl.txt', erg, function(err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
    //console.log('POSTed: ' + in1);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(postHTML);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Looking at your code IMHO I'm sorry to say that you're way too far from what you want to achieve to be answered here. To give you a little pointer take a look here: http://socket.io/.

Comment: In general my code was only to show you, how the displayed part of my website is generated.

Comment: I understand there's more work in addition to the one in your question, but what I mean is that making that little form refresh it's data with server sent events will require adding frameworks like jquery using tools like bower including also socket.io, adding the listener for the file, and all that are SO questions on themself... And looking at your code it doesn't seem you've made any attempt in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a trigger function to check if the file has changed and update the view accordingly.
And why not use a template engine for displaying the view ?